# Is Google showing ads from other companies or WordPress plugin is injecting ads which are not mine?

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense, advertising

I am using WordPress for managing my blog website. I am using an Ad Injection plugin to place my ads where I want in a post. The plugin seems very good, but I saw some ads which were not from ad networks which I was using.

Now I have injected a Google ads leaderboard at some place but I saw advertisement from this advertiser: 
http://www.adroll.com/about/privacy?utm_source=evidon&utm_medium=AdChoices&utm_campaign=privacy%2Bpolicy

So I want to know whether ad injecting plugin is doing some trick or Google is using ads from other networks too?

Answer (score 1):

There are two probable answers:

1. You have ad inventory in Google DFP - where you can choose to display ads from other platform (this does not seem likely from your question)
2. Adroll is a respected remarketing platform certified by Google, Facebook and others - most likely you are are seeing ads based on previous Google searches or Facebook clicks - because that is remarketing by definition.

Just as a cautionary measure, I would also search Google for the name of the plugin you're using with the word "scam" or "review" following.

Comment: But I never subscribed for adroll